# Convert column into Json using Dataframe(python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Python   #datas from API

```
plan_get = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns) #plan_get return all json data
return Response({"MESSAGE": "FOUND","DATA":json.loads(plan_get.to_json(orient='records'))})
```

**Actual Output:**

```
[{
    "customer_name": "ABI2",
    "location_name": "Cherai2",
    "employee_name": "ASU2",
    "Sales_Plan_Details": "[{\"Month\": \"2019-1\", \"Quantity\": 10, \"Product_Gid\": 3}]"

},
{
    "customer_name": "ABI",
    "location_name": "Cherai",
    "employee_name": "ASU",
    "Sales_Plan_Details": "[{\"Month\": \"2019-1\", \"Quantity\": 10, \"Product_Gid\": 3}]"

}]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[{
    "customer_name": "ABI2",
    "location_name": "Cherai2",
    "employee_name": "ASU2",
    "Sales_Plan_Details": [{"Month": "2019-1",
        "Quantity": 10, "Product_Gid": 3}]

},
{
    "customer_name": "ABI",
    "location_name": "Cherai",
    "employee_name": "ASU",
    "Sales_Plan_Details": [{"Month": "2019-1",
        "Quantity": 10, "Product_Gid": 3}]

}]
```

Here I'm using pandas DataFrame to pass json data. My question is how would I convert `Sales_Plan_Details(column)` to JSON object before returning.

Comment: what is your desired output? please include that in your question.

Comment: I want Sales_Plan_Details column to json object

Comment: just the keys of `Sales_Plan_Details` ?

Comment: Yes ,Sales_Plan_Details values

Comment: is the json output you're getting from the statement `json.loads(plan_get.to_json(orient='records'))`

Comment: The output given in question is from json.loads(plan_get.to_json(orient='records'))

Comment: then what is your input?

Comment: Input is from API , Sales_Plan_Details row are string instead of json Object@Nihal

Comment: Please describe your question better. How can you start a question with an "Output" block??

Comment: Why negative Vote any doubt ask me. or educate me..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `json.loads` or `ast.literal_eval` for convert `string`s to `list of dicts`:

```
import ast, json

df = pd.DataFrame(rows) 
df['Sales_Plan_Details'] = df['Sales_Plan_Details'].apply(json.loads)
#alternative solution
#df['Sales_Plan_Details'] = df['Sales_Plan_Details'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

j = df.to_json(orient='records')
print (j)
[{"Sales_Plan_Details":[{"Month":"2019-1","Quantity":10,"Product_Gid":3}],
  "customer_name":"ABI2","employee_name":"ASU2","location_name":"Cherai2"},
{"Sales_Plan_Details":[{"Month":"2019-1","Quantity":10,"Product_Gid":3}],
 "customer_name":"ABI","employee_name":"ASU","location_name":"Cherai"}]
```

Setup:

```
rows= [{
                    "customer_name": "ABI2",
                    "location_name": "Cherai2",
                    "employee_name": "ASU2",
                    "Sales_Plan_Details": "[{\"Month\": \"2019-1\", \"Quantity\": 10, \"Product_Gid\": 3}]"

    },
{
                "customer_name": "ABI",
                "location_name": "Cherai",
                "employee_name": "ASU",
                "Sales_Plan_Details": "[{\"Month\": \"2019-1\", \"Quantity\": 10, \"Product_Gid\": 3}]"

}]
```

Comment: Brilliant  Thanks @jezrael

Comment: ast.literal_eval method working fine for me... Thanks @jezrael

Answer (score 1):

**You can use [list comprehensions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) to map the `Sales_Plan_Details` values.**

You can use [json.loads()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to deserialize the list value from the string.

```
import json

dataframe_json = [
    {
                    "customer_name": "ABI2",
                    "location_name": "Cherai2",
                    "employee_name": "ASU2",
                    "Sales_Plan_Details": "[{\"Month\": \"2019-1\", \"Quantity\": 10, \"Product_Gid\": 3}]"

    },
    {
                    "customer_name": "ABI",
                    "location_name": "Cherai",
                    "employee_name": "ASU",
                    "Sales_Plan_Details": "[{\"Month\": \"2019-1\", \"Quantity\": 10, \"Product_Gid\": 3}]"

    }]

# get the "Sales_Plan_Details" key value's from the list
sales_plan_details_nested_list = [sales_plan_details_dict for sales_plan_details_dict in json.loads(item("Sales_Plan_Details")) for item in dataframe_json]

# flatten the list
sales_plan_details_list = [item for sublist in sales_plan_details_nested_list for item in sublist]

# pretty print the list now
print(json.dumps(sales_plan_details_list, indent=True))
```

Comment: @selvakumar can you check now?

Comment: Thanks For Your response.. Your code really helped me @kunal